# How can I check specific checkboxes in a grid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have a `DataTable` with about five (this number may vary) products in it (`DataTable` columns are ProductID and ProductName). I also have a grid with a `CheckBox` in one column and Product name after that.

I need to check the `CheckBox`es that exist in the `DataTable`. The rest of the `CheckBox`es in the grid should remain unchecked. I have put the following code in the `ItemDataBound` event, but it's not working. All the `CheckBox`es are unchecked even though the `DataTable` shows five products.

```
dt = objProduct.GetProducts();

if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (lblname.Text.ToString() == dt.Rows[i]["ProductName"].ToString())
        {
            CheckBox1.Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (CheckBox1.Checked != true)
            {
                CheckBox1.Checked = false;
            }
            else
            {
                CheckBox1.Checked = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is the .aspx markup:

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="PName" Visible="false">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblname" Text='<%#Eval("ProductName") %>'></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblProductID" Text='<%#Eval("ProductID") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Why you have 2 If statements? Can you Post whole itemdatbound event?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate through all the rows from within the itemdatabound event. The argument scopes the controls and the datasource to the row that has just been bound.

I think you need to use the ItemDataBound event like this and set the check boxes from there

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)           
{
     //.. this is your data item for the bound row
     GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;  
     string productName = item["ProductName"].ToString();

     //.. set check boxes in here              
     CheckBox myCheckBox = e.Item.FindControl["ckBoxId"] as CheckBox;

     //.. your logic to set check box based on datasource


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simpilist in my opinion is to create a OnPreRender event for the CheckBox like:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSelector" runat="server" OnPreRender="cbSelector_OnPreRender" />
   </ItemTemplate>
   <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="25px" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then in the code behind:

```
protected void cbSelector_OnPreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyRecord record = // Get your record for the row
    CheckBox cb = sender as CheckBox;
    cb.Checked = record.Checked;
}
```